# R Plotly: subplot with table

Tags: r, plotly

I can't figure out how to make a table subplot work properly using R and Plotly.

The following demonstrates what I mean. I have two plots, one scatter and one table. Using the subplot function, the table plot does not behave as expected.

I either lose interactivity on the scatter plot, or have overlapping scatter/table plots. Please let me know if I'm missing something or if this is a bug.

I'm using plotly version 4.9.0

Thanks in advance!

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 1:10)

p1 <- 
  plot_ly(data = df,
          type = "scatter",
          mode = "line",
          x = ~x,
          y = ~y) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(fixedrange=T),
         yaxis = list(fixedrange=T)) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = F)

p2 <-
  plot_ly(
    type = 'table',
    header = list(values = c("x", "y")),
    cells = list(values = rbind(df$x, df$y))
  )


subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2) # overlapping plots

subplot(p2, p1, nrows = 2) # loses interactivity on p2

subplot(p1, p1, nrows = 2) # works as expected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just read in the documentation for Plotly:

> In Plotly there is no native way to insert a Plotly Table into a
> Subplot.

https://plot.ly/python/table-subplots/

But it seems we could create our own layout. For the table, I added 'domain' to locate it on the left side:

```
p2 <-
  plot_ly(
    type = 'table',
    domain = list(x=c(0,0.5), y=c(0,1)),
    header = list(values = c("x", "y")),
    cells = list(values = rbind(df$x, df$y))
  )
```

And then added 'layout' for the table on the left and scatterplot on the right:

```
subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(domain=c(0.5,1.0)),
         xaxis2 = list(domain=c(0,0.5)))
```

**Edit (11/30/23):**

Thanks to @YBS for recommending a function from the `manipulateWidget` package for placing a table beneath the plot. This [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/manipulateWidget/vignettes/manipulateWidgets.html) generally can:

> ...be used to create in a very easy and quick way a graphical
> interface that lets the user modify the data or the parameters of an
> interactive chart.

In this case, you can try:

```
manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(list = list(p1, p2))
```

You can also specify arguments for the number and size of rows and columns of multiple interactive plots.

Comment: Do you know how to add the frame parameter to plot_ly() in this solution? If frame is the time, I need the plot and the table to update regarding to the time. It works for the plot, but the table shows the whole table even if I add the frame parameter. So I suppose type table does not have it. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't - maybe you might want to post a separate question on this?

Comment: I did one month ago, but unfortunately, I could not find somebody to help me

Comment: Try `manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(list = list(p1, p2))` to get table below the plot.