# R: "synchronizing" plots in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, data-visualization, interactive

I am working with the R programming language. I wrote the following code to make an interactive time series "slider"

```
 library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)
    library(htmltools)
    
    library(dplyr)
#generate data
set.seed(123)

var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
 
  data$var_i = i
  data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
 
  #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
  aggregate_i = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
 
  #combine files together
 
  aggregate_i$var = i
  aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
 
  count <- count + 1
  combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
 
}

result_1 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_1$group = "group_a"
result_1$group = as.factor(result_1$group)

######

var = rnorm(731, 85,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
 
  data$var_i = i
  data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
 
  #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
  aggregate_i = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
 
  #combine files together
 
  aggregate_i$var = i
  aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
 
  count <- count + 1
  combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
 
}

result_2 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_2$group = "group_b"
result_2$group = as.factor(result_2$group)

#combine all files

final = rbind(result_1, result_2)

gg <-ggplot(final, aes(frame = var, color = group)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("title")

gg = ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

From here, I want to make 3 additional graphs corresponding to the value of "var" where the slider is currently at. I have illustrated this below (for var = 90):

[image]

Here is the R code required to make these 3 additional graphs (for var = 90):

```
#### filter for var = 90

a90 = final %>% 
  filter(var == 90)

a90 = a90 %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise( avg = mean(mean))

##bar plot

plot<-ggplot(data=a90, aes(x=group, y=avg)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("bar plot")

bar_plotly <- ggplotly(plot)


#pie chart 
 Pie = ggplot(a90, aes(x="", y=(1-avg), fill=group)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
      coord_polar("y", start=0) +ggtitle( "Pie Chart") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")+
  theme_minimal()

#for some reason this does not work
pie_plotly = ggplotly(Pie)



#table

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'table',
  columnwidth = c(100, 100),
  columnorder = c(0, 1),
  header = list(
    values = c("average","group"),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'),
    fill = list(color = c("grey", "grey")),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 14, color = "white")
  ),
  cells = list(
    values = rbind(a90$avg, a90$group),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(color = "black", width = 1),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 12, color = c("black"))
  ))

fig
```

I tried to put all the graphs together but this did not work:

```
doc <- htmltools::tagList(
  div(gg, style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
  div(bar_plotly,style = "float:left;width:50%;"),
  div(fig, style = "float:left;width:50%;"))

htmltools::save_html(html = doc, file = "final.html")

Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

Can someone please tell me if this is possible to update the other graphs as the user slides the slider for the first graph?

Thanks

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.6.0       htmltools_0.5.1.1 dplyr_1.0.3       plotly_4.9.3      ggplot2_3.3.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6         later_1.1.0.1      pillar_1.4.7       compiler_4.0.3     RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_4.0.3       
 [7] digest_0.6.27      jsonlite_1.7.2     lifecycle_0.2.0    tibble_3.0.5       gtable_0.3.0       viridisLite_0.3.0 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.10       cli_2.2.0          rstudioapi_0.13    crosstalk_1.1.1    yaml_2.2.1        
[19] fastmap_1.1.0      withr_2.4.1        httr_1.4.2         generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.6        htmlwidgets_1.5.3 
[25] grid_4.0.3         tidyselect_1.1.0   glue_1.4.2         data.table_1.13.6  R6_2.5.0           fansi_0.4.2       
[31] purrr_0.3.4        tidyr_1.1.2        farver_2.0.3       magrittr_2.0.1     promises_1.1.1     scales_1.1.1      
[37] ellipsis_0.3.1     assertthat_0.2.1   xtable_1.8-4       mime_0.9           colorspace_2.0-0   httpuv_1.5.5      
[43] labeling_0.4.2     lazyeval_0.2.2     munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [plotly's tutorial](https://plotly.com/r/subplot-charts/), the way to combine different plots is to use `subplot`. By doing this, it also links the slider to all plots if you defined the frame argument in all plots (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713761/one-slider-controlling-multiple-subplots-in-r)).

Also, for these more complicated plots, I think it is always safer to work directly in the `plotly` API instead of converting a `ggplot`

```
# create summary dataframe for bar chart and pie chart
df.summary <- final %>% group_by(group, var) %>%
  summarise( avg = mean(mean)) %>% ungroup()

# create line chart
gg <- final %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~month, y = ~mean, frame=~var, color=~group, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', colors = 'Set1') %>% 
  layout(showlegend = F)

# create bar chart
bar_plotly <- df.summary %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~group, y = ~avg, frame=~var, color=~group, ids=groups, type = 'bar', colors = 'Set1') %>% 
  layout(showlegend = F, yaxis = list(range = c(0, 0.7)))

# create pie chart
Pie <- df.summary %>% 
  plot_ly(values = ~avg, frame=~var, ids=groups, type = 'pie', domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0, 0.4)), colors = 'Set1') %>% 
  layout(showlegend = F)

# combine all of them into one interactive plot
subplot(gg, subplot(bar_plotly, Pie, nrows = 2), nrows = 1)
```

[image]

[According to plotly](https://plotly-r.com/animating-views.html#animation-support), not all traces fully support animations. So the transitions in the pie chart will not be smooth.

Also, I don't think you can link the table with the current plotly API.

Another option would be to create a shiny application, where you could have more control.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Everything works perfectly! found a small typo : df.summary <- final %>% group_by(group, var) %>%
  summarise( avg = mean(mean)) %>% ungroup() %>% .... there was an extra "%>%" at the end

Comment: Can you please tell me how you posted the animation in the answer?

Comment: Note: I think I found a way to save the final file ..... sub = subplot(gg, subplot(bar_plotly, Pie, nrows = 2), nrows = 1); library(htmltools);  saveWidget(
    sub,
    "file.html")

Comment: if possible, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109378/adding-multiple-sliders-to-the-same-graph thank you

Comment: @Noob. Thanks for catching the typo. I will fix it. Regarding the gif I posted: I recorded my screen using Quicktime (I am using a mac) and then converted the video to gif using an online tool (you can also do this [using ffmpeg/ImageMagick commands](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality))

Comment: @Noob, I had a look at the other question. I don't think you can create two independent sliders using the standard plotly API. But I think you can get something like that using shiny. I will give a try and I will post there if I manage to get somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found something which shows how to use multiple sliders: https://plotly.com/r/sliders/ .... now, i am trying to recreate the example from this website using my data

Comment: I had seen that one too! But I think that one is not an animation (but it is really cool). It is just redrawing the map with the new lat/long values. You can see that it does not define the `frame` aesthetic in any place. So you end up loosing the smooth transition effect that you had in your line plot. The approach I was trying with shiny was similar to this. I think I have something close enough. I will post there.

Comment: I tried to add a table: 
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'table',
  columnwidth = c(100, 100),
  columnorder = c(0, 1),
  header = list(
    values = c("average","group"),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(width = 1, color = 'black'),
    fill = list(color = c("grey", "grey")),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 14, color = "white")
  ),
  cells = list(
    values = rbind(df.summary$group, df.summary$var),
    align = c("center", "center"),
    line = list(color = "black", width = 1),
    font = list(family = "Arial", size = 12, color = c("black"))
  ))

Comment: But the code does not seem to be working anymore: subplot(gg, subplot(bar_plotly, fig, Pie, nrows = 2), nrows = 1) ... am i doing something wrong? thank you for all your help

Comment: (i am not sure where the "frame = var" statement needs to be placed in the table)

Comment: @Noob I don't think plotly tables have a `frame` atribute. I don't think you can update them with the slider. Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267164/r-plotly-subplot-with-table). They also mention this limitation. Maybe if you start customizing with javascript. But this is too advanced for me... There is a [good tutorial online about plotly/shiny](https://plotly-r.com/). I am taking a look at it. If I find a solution I will update my answer. Anyway, working with `shiny` would give you more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for everything. Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141967/r-switching-between-graphs thank you

Comment: do you have any idea if the code you wrote in this question can be applied to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699881/interactive-plots-in-r ?